# Is there a way to pass some value to a serviceworker to use during the install step?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Is there a way to pass a value to the service worker so it can use during the install step?

As an example, if your webpage resources are in a folder that is based on the release version of the project (`resource-2.11/js/...`). At some point  you need to know `resource-2.11` to cache some of the files. Can this value be passed in?

Comment: Could you make it a build step rather than determining it dynamically at runtime?

Comment: @TimoSta  Yeah that would solve the problem in my case.

Would still be useful to know if serviceworkers can take in some kind of parameters, based on everything i'm seeing it's not possible :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few different approaches.

Generating your `service-worker.js` file at build time is probably the right approach, as suggested in the comments. This has the advantage of ensuring that the `install` event will fire whenever there's a change to your versioned prefix, since any change to the contents of `service-worker.js` is enough to trigger a [service worker update](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/service-worker/lifecycle#updates).

But, if you can't do that for some reason, another answer to the general question of "how do you pass a value to a service worker that's available during installation" is to use [`IndexedDB`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API). You can set a value from the main page, then register the service worker, and then the service worker can read in the value. You should note that changing the value in `IndexedDB` from the main page will **not** trigger a service worker update, though.

And finally, there's another approach that you could use if you want to trigger service worker updates whenever the value changes, but for some reason you can't modify `service-worker.js` during a build step. That's to include the value as a URL query parameter that's appended to the end of the `service-worker.js` when you register it from the page:

```
// From your web page:
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  const value = encodeURIComponent('some-parameter-value');
  const swUrl = `service-worker.js?_param=${value}`;
  navigator.serviceWorker.register(swUrl);
}

// From your service worker:
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  const selfUrl = new URL(self.location);
  // Uses https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams
  const parameterValue = selfUrl.searchParams.get('_param');
  // Do something with parameterValue
});
```

Registering a service worker with a different URL will trigger a service worker update that's equivalent to changing the contents of your `service-worker.js`.