# Inject parameter in Service Worker

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use the Service Worker but a the moment of registration I get this error:

[image: Js Error]

I got that the service worker can't subscribe because the evaluation of the script failed, but I don't get why "Username" is not defined, cause if I debug it I can see the value inside it, and inside the service worker the value is passed correctly, but I can't figure out why "Username" is not defined. Help please!

This is the start and the end of the Sevice Worker:

[image: The script in my View]

This is the Service Worker:

[image: The start and the end of the Sevice Worker]

Comment: Please add your code and error as text to the question, not as an image

Comment: Note that the script show in the picture, which shows `var Username = '@user.Username' || "";`, the `|| ""` will never be taken. If `user.Username` is undefined, the JavaScript variable `Username` will be the string "undefined".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing state info into a service worker before \`install\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44424709/passing-state-info-into-a-service-worker-before-install)

Comment: See also [Is there a way to pass some value to a serviceworker to use during the install step?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40387983/215552)

Answer (score 0):

You can inject parameter in url during registration

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.register("my-service-worker.js?someParam=someValue")
```

and inside `my-service-worker.js` you can read it as follows

```js
var param = null;

self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    param = new URL(location).searchParams.get('someParam');
});
```

you can add more params using `&` separator